# How do you increase range of an antenna and wifi adapter usb?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Is there any way I am able to increase the range of wifi using my 25dbi yagi antenna and alfa awus036h wifi adapter? Without buying another antenna. Is there any like amp that will make it go farther?

Thanks, Jason

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This might not be a solution if your problem is interference from home appliances or nearby wifi networks. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest route will most likely be buying a bigger antenna. Inline WiFi amps are very expensive.

http://www.radiolabs.com/products/wireless/wireless-inline-amplifier.php

Answer (score 0):

As @ubiquibacon stated you can get an inline amp, but they are not neccessarily as expensive as the one he quoted.  I [found](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008VP5H2M) one from Amazon for $41.  (Note this is not a recommendation or endorsement, I have had some amps before - a long time ago - and I very much doubt they were anything like as expensive as the the one ubiquibacon found).  Of-course, cheaper amps will probably produce more noise, so they may get you further range, but they are not a panacea - and probably not as good as expensive ones.

That said, if your antenna is already putting out 1watt (as the specs seem to indicate), you may be better off upgrading to 802.11n equipment - which gives substantially further range - about 40% further, with a greater upside maximum speed.

Another thing to try - if you havn't already - is rotating your current Yagi by 90 degrees, which may cut down the amount of noise it picks up and thus boosts your signal - if its a point-to-point direction do this on both ends.